# Counting number of points per feature unique Id in lidR

Tags: r, lidr, dplyr

I am working with a LAScatalog comprising over 10 LAS files and have generated a fishnet grid with 1m x 1m cells upto the extent of my ROI. Each cell in the ROI grid is uniquely identified by an 'Id' column. My objective is to calculate the total number of points and total number of returns within each 'Id' cell for my research. Each LAS file has an average point density of 30-40 points per square meter.

```
# Importing the ROI with Id
cropped = st_read('abc.shp')
point = function(las)
{
    las <- readLAS(las)               # read the chunk
    if (is.empty(las)) return(NULL)
    las_df = payload(las)
    # then convert LAS data to an sf object 
    las_sf <- st_as_sf(las_df, coords = c("X", "Y"), crs = st_crs(cropped))
    joined_data <- st_join(las_sf, cropped)
    #sum(is.na(joined_data$Newcol)
    print('Leading to Step 1 !!')
    # used multiple cores using dplyr
    cluster <- new_cluster(28)
    cluster
    print('Cluster created !!')
    joined_data_1 <- joined_data %>%
      group_by(Id) %>%
      mutate(total_points = n()) %>%
      partition(cluster) %>% #To partition jobs among multiple cores
      ungroup()
    print('joined_data_1 party df created !!')
    sf_joined <- cropped %>%
          left_join(joined_data_1 , by = c("Id" = "Id"))
    return(sf_joined)
 }

opt_output_files(ctg) = "Lidar_metric/{ORIGINALFILENAME}_Re"
options <- list(automerge = TRUE) # merge all the outputs
print("Applying my function")
out <- catalog_apply(ctg, point, .options = options)
print('filter_p function run')
```

This give me total points at each Id like 7661824 which I cant understand where I am getting wrong.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a very typical use case of `pixel_metrics`

```r
mymetric = function(rn)
{
  npoints = length(rn)
  npulses = sum(rn == 1)
  return(list(npoints = npoints, npulses = npulses))
}

m <- pixel_metrics(ctg, ~mymetric(ReturnNumber), res = 1)
```

Comment: Great JRR, but how about using my shapefile's column? I have rest of my functions(did not paste whole here) designed accordingly, so ca you suggest in that manner?

Comment: Why do you want to use a shapefile to produce what is actually a raster? In terms of computation workload this sounds a very bad idea. If you really want to combine the raster and the shapefile I'm sure you can use `sf` and `terra` to extract the raster values with dedicated tools. If done properly, it will be simpler and more efficient.

Comment: So continuing to which lets say I have added lasattribute 'nc' in my lascatalog and now I want to get the proportion of nc = Shrub at each grid, so will the following code help me-

abc= function(z, rn, nc)
{ 
 list(
    npoints = length(rn)
    Shrub_prop = (sum(nc == 'Shrub')/npoints)
}

Comment: Yes but `nc` cannot be a string. It is not possible to store extra attribute as string in a las file.

Comment: So does it I should give numeric code to Shrub and other vegetation classes? Right 
OR
as now I am getting this Error: object 'nc' not found. Or I have to make new name to nc without putting it in ""? So sorry for being naive!!!

Comment: Please open a new question with details and a reproducible example. My crystal ball reached its limit.